# Is it possible to fire EditValueChanged event in CheckedComboBoxEdit control immediately after the item has been checked

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, devexpress

I need to update the edit value of the CheckedComboBoxEdit control immediately after the item has been checked

Answer (score 0):

The `MouseUp` event can be used to trigger `EndEdit`which will commit the change slightly faster.

I used this to solve my simular issue when working with a CheckBox within a DateGridView. As by default the event to submit changes in a DataGridView only fires when leaving the cell.

Comment: not working properly. i want that when i am checked any item then its fire the event.

Comment: Let me explain it a slightly better, `MouseUp` will trigger when you release your mouse button, In this event you can call `EndEdit` and then you can  use the `ValueChanged` event to determine if the box was checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe `Popup` event of CheckedComboBoxEdit, find `CheckedListBoxControl` and subscribe `ItemCheck` event. Like this:

```
    void _orgStructEntitesCheckedComboBoxEdit_Popup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var popup = (IPopupControl)sender;

        var control = popup.PopupWindow.Controls.OfType<PopupContainerControl>().First().Controls.OfType<CheckedListBoxControl>().First();

        control.ItemCheck += control_ItemCheck;
    }

    void control_ItemCheck(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        var checkedListBoxControl = (CheckedListBoxControl)sender;
        var current = checkedListBoxControl.Items[e.Index];
    }
```

Use `e.Index` to get current item changed.

More information [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q131357) and [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q344795).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i have implemented this but i want that when in  checked item of this combobox then it take me to change event and on some logic i want to check that its make unchecked or not. only want recent checked value.

Comment: @HarshDesai i don't understand you, in my code method control_ItemCheck fires when item in combobox checked or unchecked, what is wrong?

Comment: how can i able to get specific checked item when i am checking that item.

Comment: @HarshDesai you can get it from `e` argument, I updated my answer